# addClass not working while trying to dynamically change class of a div

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/hdn6e/10/

what is wrong here? Have tried everything at my end but nothing seems to be working

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="qty" style="float:left">1</div>
    <div class="name" >A</div>    
</div>
<div id="main">
    <div class="qty" style="float:left">2</div>
    <div class="name">B</div>    
</div>
<input type="button" id="ADD">


$('#main').on('click', function(){
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
$('.name').on('click', function(){
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
$('.qty').on('click', function(){
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });

$('#ADD').click( function(){
        $(".selected").nearest(".qty").text($(".selected").nearest(".qty").text() +1);
    });
```

Comment: You might want to take a look at your web browser's console.

Comment: `nearest` method is a problem.

Comment: Maby put in a $(document).ready({...)}

Comment: I have tried just adding a class to each also, doesnt work

Comment: You also have two elements with `id="main"`..

Comment: document.ready is also not helping...there is something else wrong here. I just want to add class "selected" to the div I click

Comment: it works for me http://jsfiddle.net/hdn6e/11/

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is that your second `<div id="main">` is not getting the `selected` class, that is because you cannot have more than one item on the DOM with the same ID as you do in [your jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/hdn6e/10/).

Change `main` to be a class and it will work as expected.

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="qty" style="float:left">1</div>
    <div class="name" >A</div>    
</div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="qty" style="float:left">2</div>
    <div class="name">B</div>    
</div>
<input type="button" id="ADD">
```

**JS**

```
$('.main').on('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ye4MF/)**

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to add a CSS class to each clicked element. If you want to add a class attribute, do the following:

```
$('#main').on('click', function(){
    $(this).attr('class', 'selected');
});
```

If you want to apply a CSS class, create the selected class in the style tags

```
<style>
    .selected {
        color: blue;
    }
</style>
```

Then add it to the clicked element with

```
.addClass("selected");
```